# collect all .o in subdirectories - makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the following hierarchy:

```
+ makefile
|
+ TT_Project1
|      obj/
|      makefile
+ TT_Project2
|      obj/
|      makefile
+ TT_Project3
|      obj/
|      makefile
```

The top level makefile calls recursively all makefiles below it, each compiles the .cpp to .o and places it under `/obj`

I would like to collect all `.o` in the top level to create a static library. And failing as my output library is too small...

```
TT := libTT.a

SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)
OBJECTS := $(wildcard $(addsuffix *.o,$(SUBDIRS)/obj))

all: $(TT) $(OBJECTS)

$(TT) : $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $(TT) $(OBJECTS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

I can clearly see that it's running the makefiles beneath it, and they are placing the `*.o` under their `/obj` as expected. But I am failing to grab all the `.o` I guess... any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is wrong:

```
OBJECTS := $(wildcard $(addsuffix *.o,$(SUBDIRS)/obj))
```

Not only are you missing a `/` between the `obj` and `*.o`, but you need to put the `/obj` in the first argument to `addsuffix`.  Suppose `SUBDIRS` ends up as `foo/. bar/. baz/.`.  Then the `addsuffix` will expand to:

```
$(addsuffix *.o,foo/. bar/. baz/./obj)
```

which gives:

```
foo/.*o bar/.*.o baz/./obj*.o
```

which is clearly wrong.  You want this:

```
OBJECTS := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /obj/*.o,$(SUBDIRS)))
```

However, that *isn't* what you want.  It won't work because these variables are expanded when the makefile is read, before any actions have been taken.  Before the makefile actually builds anything, there will be no `.o` files existing, which means the `wildcard` function will match nothing.

In your case that's a good thing, because if it *did* match anything you'll get errors because make doesn't know how to build those objects: they're built by the sub-makes.

But, since you have nothing that depends on the `SUBDIRS` target they won't get built anyway: those recipes will never run.

The easiest thing you can do is something like this:

```
TT := libTT.a

SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

all: $(TT)

$(TT) : $(SUBDIRS)
        ar rcs $(TT) $(addsuffix /obj/*.o,$(SUBDIRS))

$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@
.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)
```

The downside of this is that it will rebuild the library every time you run `make` even if no objects have been changed.  To fix that you'll have to add some complexity.

Comment: One question, if in the future I decide to add additional directories, how to modify `SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)` to only add directories starting with `TT_`?

Comment: `wildcard` uses normal shell globbing.  So you'd use `$(wildcard TT_*/.)`